Can Mermaid JS generate nested/embedded block components and reference them via a dict "[]" or dot notation "."?
Given a diagram that looks like this following:

Where the components are defined in a nested manner, something like (ignore the actual semantics as I'm generalizing, though I'm welcome to full example):
component {
  name: A
  component {
    name: B
    ports {
      name: p1
    }
  }
...

Can you access nested components like any:
1)  A.B.p1 --> C.D.E.p4
2)  [A][B][p.1] --> [C][D][E][p.4]
3)  A["B"]["p.1"] --> C["D"]["E"]["p.4"]

I'm only generally seeing support for coding the connections like below. Even when components might be defined in a nested structure, the connection endpoints have to have a unique name:
1)  p.1 --> p.4
2)  A.B --> C.D.E (This fails, instead it creates NEW components "A.B"...)
3)  B[p.1] --> E[p.4] (Haven't ever seen this)

I've can define types to hack what looks like what I'm asking but it's not true nested access, via subgraph a["A"]; subgraph a.b["B"]; a.b.p1["p.1"], see: https://mermaid.live/edit#pako:eNptkLEKgzAQhl8l3KwBwcmh0NZu7dKOTYdozioYDTEZivjuPQ2Igtvxfcd_PzdC2SuEDL5Wmprdn8KKjrHBFwHIt4CzgE_AW8ELUpeNYjPjJiFseLIR2KkwrsOaUtLy9Si-5IpUvovfSo6kbzvNAucmXRqkO7mePqoTerM4Pq0RQUAEGq2WjaIPjTMR4GrUKCCjUWElfesEiG6iVeld__p1JWTOeozAGyUd5o2k1hqySrYDUVSN6-0jfH15_vQHH0h49A
